# How to do SSO with Google Cloud Identity Platform?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I have two react apps and i'm trying do SSO with Google Cloud identity Platform, but it's not working. can anyone help me here?

At Google Cloud Platform:

1. I have created a project named 'abc'.
2. Enabled google cloud identity platform for this project.
3. At the Identity platform section, added one provider email/password and created a dummy user.

At React-app-1  project

1. Installed firebase and react-firebaseui packages.
2. Configured apiKey and authDomain properly and it's working fine. I can log in with  dummy user.
3. This app is running at http://localhost:3000

At React-app-2  project

1. Installed firebase and react-firebaseui packages.
2. Configured with same apiKey and authDomain.
3. This app is running at http://localhost:3001

My expectation is, if I logged in to app-1 in a browser tab, then app-2 running in another tab of the same browser should not popup login form as I already logged in to app-1.

But app-2 is showing the login form again. It's not doing SSO. How i can achieve SSO ?

I'm using StyledFirebaseAuth Component from `react-firebaseui` package.

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
```

Comment: The front end has nothing to do with SSO, to say the least. Setup an authentication server and in the callback URL of gauth open iframe and setup cookies to make every domain authenticated. Also, this is one way to achieve.

Comment: thanks, @ChandraKumar . Can't understand fully. Can you please provide me with any document/resource link?

Comment: localhost:3000 and localhost:3001 are entirely different domains. Google authorizes localhost:3000(requesting site) to access user name and email etc. This is what you have achieved using firebase auth. So Google has no idea about localhost:3001 since for google it's a different domain. 
To achieve this you have to set up your own server. Check https://workos.com/blog/firebase-auth-and-sso